# Обработка ошибки Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

Суть проблемы такова что при чтении API с сервера я получаю 3 параметра "status, error, print" но бывает так что сервер может не отдать 1 из полей например "status, error" а "print" отсутствует, либо может быть ошибка в ответе например "status, error, " тоесть лишний символ в ответе, приложение крашится,  причем крашится в тихую без вывода логов, как отловить ошибку и вывести сообщение оставив приложение в рабочем состоянии.

```
    interface PrintApi {

    @GET
    suspend fun getPrintCommands(@Url url: String, @Query("bib") bib: Int?, @Query("card") card: String): PrintResponse
}


@Keep
@Serializable
data class PrintResponse(
    val ok: Boolean? = false,
    val error: String = readLine() ?: "", //test
    val printout: List<PrintCmd>? = null
)
```

вызов:

```
  private suspend fun getCommands(url: String, bib: Int?, tagNumber: String): List<PrintCmd>? {
        try {
            val result = api.getPrintCommands(url, bib, tagNumber) // приложение молча падает на этой строчке

            if (result.ok == true && result.error.isBlank()  && result.printout != null)
            {
            return result.print
            }
            else
            {
                return null
            }
        } catch (e: HttpException) {
            Log.e("TEST", e.message())
            Logger.w(e)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e("TEST", e.toString())
            Logger.w(e)
        }
        return null
    }
```

Вот так выглядит рабочий JSON файл:

```
{   "ok":true, "error":"ERROR_PRINT","printout" : [] }
```

Вот так выглядит ответ битого JSON файла:

```
{   "ok":true, "error":"ERROR_PRINT", }
```

Удалось получить ошибку

> Failed to invoke private ru.osport.osportnfc.model.api.PrintCmd() with
> no args

Сам класс PrintCmd:

```
@Keep
@Serializable
sealed class PrintCmd()
```

который наследует

```
@Keep
@Serializable
@SerialName("normal_text")
data class PrintTextCmd(
    val content: String,
    val font_size: Int,
    val align: String,
    val bold: Boolean,
    val italic: Boolean
) : PrintCmd()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приложение молча падает потому что крэш надо ловить в `coroutineExceptionHandler`
Тема с трай кетч тут не прокатит. Даже хотя бы его добавить то падать перестанет

у ретрофита есть `Response` , можно завернуть `Responce<PrintResponse>` и потом поймать котлиновским `Result`, поймать типа `result.run catching`

- Не совсем понятно что это `Json` или что то другое, покажите как выглядит ответ включая неправильный.

Comment: ```Response``` делать под него отдельную функцию \ класс ? Можно например обьявить внутри функции ```getCommands``` Мне просто нужно понять почему крашит, я уже настолько устал отлавливать ошибки с корутинами что мне кажется проще переписать все под RxJava ((

Comment: обновил вопрос, получается фаткически я могу не получить 1 поле из-за ошибки правок на стороне сервера, так как приложение крутится на большенстве клиентов, оно просто падает молча у всех, а мне нужно что бы и приложение не крашило и в нужном поле статус ошибки отобразило.

Comment: suspend fun getPrintCommands(@Url url: String, @Query("bib") bib: Int?, @Query("card") card: String): Responce<PrintResponse>

Comment: suspend fun getPrintCommands(@Url url: String, @Query("bib") bib: Int?, @Query("card") card: String): Responce<PrintResponse>/ getCommands вызывается из вьюмодели? там где стартует в билдер корутины нужно положить coroutineExceptionHandler

Comment: Нет ```getCommands``` вызывается из сервиса, а после уже и вьюмодели ```@Singleton
class PrintService @Inject constructor(
    private val printManager: PrinterManager,
    @AppScope coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    private val api: PrintApi,
    private val eventRepository: EventRepository
) : CoroutineScope by coroutineScope {getCommands} //полностью функцию переписывать не стал ```

Comment: Удалось отловить ошибку ```Failed to invoke private ru.osport.osportnfc.model.api.PrintCmd() with no args``` как фиксить подобное ?